# How to simplify call syntax to function which accepts generic method pointer C++14

Tags: c++

I'm designing a message queue for an Actor system, where the message queue contains std::function objects.  The client code to add a message to the queue has complex syntax which I'd like to simplify.  Some example code:

```
class Actor
{
    std::deque<std::function<void()>> fMessageQueue;

    template <class F, class ... Args>
    void AddMessage(F &&fn, Args && ... args)
    {
        fMessageQueue.push_back(std::bind(std::forward<F>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
}

class MyActor : public Actor
{
    void Behaviour1(float arg) {/*do something*/}
}
```

To use the above classes, I'd do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    MyActor a;
    a.AddMessage(&MyActor::Behaviour1, &a, 1.0f);  // redundant 2nd argument &a, needed by std::bind()
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use the following code syntax:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    MyActor a;
    a.AddMessage(&MyActor::Behaviour1, 1.0f);  // notice no 2nd argument &a
}
```

I would like the client API to not require the 2nd instance of 'a' (used as 2nd argument to std::bind()).

While searching the net, I managed to find something close to what I'd like to achieve, but the argument syntax is reversed:

```
template <class M> struct Behaviour;
template <class C, class ... Args> struct Behaviour<void(C::*)(Args ...)>
{
    using M = void (C::*)(Args ...);
    template <M mp> static void Call(C *target, Args && ... args)
    {
        target->fMessageQueue.push_back(std::bind(mp, target, args ...));
    }
};
#define MSG(m) Behaviour<decltype(m)>::Call<m>
```

And the example call usage would be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyActor a;
    Actor::MSG(&MyActor::Behaviour1)(&a, 1.0f);
}
```

This is slightly more legible, but still not quite like my ideal call syntax.  I also dont like the macro MSG.  The easiest API call syntax would be:

```
a.AddMessage(&MyActor::Behaviour1, 1.0f);
```

Does anyone know how I can simplify the call syntax so that the client doesn't have to specify argument #2?

Comment: why can't you do `bind(fn, this, args...)` in `AddMessage`? (simplified)

Comment: That is the first thing I tried.  The compiler error is "Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(__Callable &&, __Types && ...)"  Most likely the error is due to type deduction rules for a generic 'this' pointer, which I haven't been able to resolve. 'this' works find for fixed method pointers, but not for generic method pointers.  And I dont know the template magic to cast 'this' to the required type (hence my question to Stack Overflow).